# Transfer Learning, adding Keras LSTM layer, (hot dog, not hot dog using binary cross-entropy)

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, lstm

The training features, shape (1032, 5, 5, 122880), go into an LSTM layer.  This produces "ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_16: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2"

1032 is the number of training samples

5x5x122880 is the training sample's bottlenecked features

```
model = Sequential()
    model.add(CuDNNLSTM(2048,input_shape=train_final_model.shape[:1))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='sigmoid'))
```

It seems as though the Keras ValueError is telling me that I should reshape the training bottlenecked features before running them through the LSTM layer.  But doing that:

```
training_bottlenecked_features = np.reshape(train_final_model, (1032,25,122880))
print(training_bottlenecked_features.shape)
final_model.add(LSTM(2,input_shape=training_bottlenecked_features.shape[:1]))
```

Yields this:

(1032, 25, 122880)

"ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_23: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2"

I've played around with the input in several other combinations, so I feel I may be missing something fundamental in the Keras LSTM documentation: https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/  Thank you for any insight you may have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that LSTM and RNNs rely on using keras.layers.TimeDistributed.  This requires minimally restructuring the training and validation label dimensions (e.g. using np.expand_dims()).

If TimeDistributed is used to wrap the entire Sequential flow, you will likely also need to reshape the training and validation data.

The dialog here is helpful for recalling recurrent network architectural distinctions:
https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/1029

Reflecting back, I wish I would have started reading here:
https://keras.io/layers/wrappers/